# DynamoDB list all backups using AWS GoLang SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

Based on the example given in the link blow on API Operation Pagination without Callbacks 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/context-pattern-added-to-the-aws-sdk-for-go/
I am trying to list all the Backups in dynamodb. But it seems like  pagination is not working and it is just retrieving first page and not going to next page

```
package main

    import (
        "context"
        "fmt"

        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request"

        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
    )

    func main() {

        sess, sessErr := session.NewSession()

        if sessErr != nil {
            fmt.Println(sessErr)
            fmt.Println("Cound not initilize session..returning..")
            return
        }
        // Create DynamoDB client
        dynamodbSvc := dynamodb.New(sess)

        params := dynamodb.ListBackupsInput{}
        ctx := context.Background()

        p := request.Pagination{
            NewRequest: func() (*request.Request, error) {
                req, _ := dynamodbSvc.ListBackupsRequest(&params)
                req.SetContext(ctx)
                return req, nil
            },
        }

        for p.Next() {
            page := p.Page().(*dynamodb.ListBackupsOutput)
            fmt.Println("Received", len(page.BackupSummaries), "objects in page")
            for _, obj := range page.BackupSummaries {
                fmt.Println(aws.StringValue(obj.BackupName))
            }
        }
        //return p.Err()
    } //end of main
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit late but I'll just put it here in case I can help somebody.

Example:

```
var exclusiveStartARN *string
var backups []*dynamodb.BackupSummary
    for {
        backup, err := svc.ListBackups(&dynamodb.ListBackupsInput{
            ExclusiveStartBackupArn:exclusiveStartARN,
        })

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        backups = append(backups, backup.BackupSummaries...)
        if backup.LastEvaluatedBackupArn != nil {
            exclusiveStartARN = backup.LastEvaluatedBackupArn
            //max 5 times a second so we dont hit the limit
            time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
            continue
        }
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(len(backups))
```

Explaination:

The way that pagination is done is via `ExclusiveStartBackupArn` in the ListBackupsRequest. The ListBackupsResponse returns LastEvaluatedBackupArn if there are more pages, or nil if its the last/only page.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're smashing into the API a bit with your usage

> You can call ListBackups a maximum of 5 times per second.

What is the value of `p.HasNextPage()` in your `p.Next()` loop?

Comment: Are you sure you have another page? I know that sounds dumb, but it's worth asking to be sure you know how many pages are there.

Comment: Yes i am sure there are lot of backups. So there should be more pages. Seems like some bug with the api?

Comment: Perhaps. One of the biggest issues with the golang AWS SDK is the inconsistencies between pagination APIs - I wasn't even able to find someone else *using* this functionality on github to reference myself. I would suggest trying the same code, but specifying the table, and seeing if your mileage varies. If not, perhaps their issue tracker might be a better spot. Unfortunately this seems very, very specific.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.